# Get string between two substrings

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to get a string between two substrings.

For example:

Code:

```
'{{something}} Space {}} Space2 {{}}'.match(/{(.*?)}/g)
```

I want it to be:

```
['{something}','}','{}']
```

but it returns:

```
['{{something}','{}','{{}']
```

Comment: So how do you want to distinguish your preferred response from one that would return, say `['{something}} Space {}} Space2 {{}']` as the response?  That is, what is allowed outside the brackets that is not allowed inside?  Is it space characters?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it would get the answer you want in this case, but the general case is not very clear to me:

```
'{{something}} Space {}}'.match(/{([^{]*?)}/g)
```

Comment: for more genaral case you might want to use `(?<={)(.*?)}` as the regex provided here wont match correctly some thing like this `{{something}} Space {{([^{]*?)}}`

Comment: I have found a solution for my problem

Comment: Care to share that solution?